# how not to start videos automatically?

Tags: php

hello friends i am having a problem when implementing my php code on my website i bring the videos from the database what is happening when accessing the page all videos are autoplaying at the same time causing a site crash how do i solve this problem I don't want the videos to start automatically but when the user clicks on the video he wants to thank you guys!
follow the code:

```
 <div class="row">
            <?php extract($this->Dados['sts_videos'][1]); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="lead text-center mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></p>
                <iframe class="ml-4 mt-4" width="560" height="315" 
                src="<?php echo URL . '/assets/video/site/video_opiniao/'
                    . $id . '/' . $video; ?>" alt="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
                </iframe>
                <p class="lead ml-4 mt-4">Descrição do video:
                    <p class="lead ml-4 mt-2"><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php extract($this->Dados['sts_videos'][2]); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="lead text-center mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></p>
                <iframe class="ml-4 mt-4" width="560" height="315" 
                src="<?php echo URL . '/assets/video/site/video_opiniao/'
                    . $id . '/' . $video; ?>" alt="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
                </iframe>
                <p class="lead ml-4 mt-4">Descrição do video:
                    <p class="lead ml-4 mt-2"><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="my-2">
        <div class="row">
            <?php extract($this->Dados['sts_videos'][3]); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="lead text-center mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></p>
                <iframe class="ml-4 mt-4" width="560" height="315" 
                src="<?php echo URL . '/assets/video/site/video_opiniao/'
                    . $id . '/' . $video; ?>" alt="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
                </iframe>
                <p class="lead ml-4 mt-4">Descrição do video:
                    <p class="lead ml-4 mt-2"><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php extract($this->Dados['sts_videos'][4]); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="lead text-center mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></p>
                <iframe class="ml-4 mt-4" width="560" height="315" 
                src="<?php echo URL . '/assets/video/site/video_opiniao/'
                    . $id . '/' . $video; ?>" alt="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
                </iframe>
                <p class="lead ml-4 mt-4">Descrição do video:
                    <p class="lead ml-4 mt-2"><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="my-2">
        <div class="row">
            <?php extract($this->Dados['sts_videos'][5]); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="lead text-center mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></p>
                <iframe class="ml-4 mt-4" width="560" height="315" 
                src="<?php echo URL . '/assets/video/site/video_opiniao/'
                    . $id . '/' . $video; ?>" alt="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
                </iframe>
                <p class="lead ml-4 mt-4">Descrição do video:
                    <p class="lead ml-4 mt-2"><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php extract($this->Dados['sts_videos'][6]); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="lead text-center mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></p>
                <iframe class="ml-4 mt-4" width="560" height="315" 
                src="<?php echo URL . '/assets/video/site/video_opiniao/'
                    . $id . '/' . $video; ?>" alt="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
                </iframe>
                <p class="lead ml-4 mt-4">Descrição do video:
                    <p class="lead ml-4 mt-2"><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: hi mateus, not sure what exactly is going on in your code, please elaborate, translate and reduce it to the minimal problem so we can understand and help you.

Comment: sure what happens is that when I access the page of videos all videos start playing at the same time I want to know how I can stop this in my code

Comment: friends I managed to solve my problem modifying to:                                             
    <video controls="true" class="embed-responsive-item">
      <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
thank you guys!